# php vs c++ hmac inconsistent

Tags: php, c++, hmac

I am trying to integrate a game engine(c++) and a server(php)

c++

```
char key[] = "012345678";

// The data that we're going to hash using HMAC
char hashStr[] = "hello world";

unsigned char* result = HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key, strlen(key) , (unsigned char*)hashStr, strlen(hashStr), NULL, NULL);
```

php

```
$key = "012345678";
$msg = "hello world";


$hash = hash_hmac ( 'sha256' , $msg ,  $key , true );

echo(bin2hex($hash));
```

The problem is my hashes do not match up and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.